# Need to write a batch script to copy a single EXCEL file into all sub-folders that the EXCEL file is currently in

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy-paste

I have an Excel template that I will be needing to copy into hundreds of folders.  I want to create a batch script that will do this for me.

**Here's the catch:** I need this to work based on whatever folder the batch file is in. I need a script that can be run from whatever the directory the batch file is in **without specifying a specific directory or destination**. The script will detect that excel file and then copy it into every subfolder in that directory.

Everything I've found so far requires you to specify the directory and destination. I would like something that can be moved to any computer and work based on the setup shown below:

[image]

Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The code isn't really any different whether you are specifying the directory or not. Show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Use `%~dp0` to refer to the drive\folder the batch resides in. And a `for /r "%~dp0" %%A in (.) do echo %%A` to enumerate all folders recursively from there

Comment: @Squashman This is my first time trying to write a btach script but heres what I have: `for /r  %~dp0 %i in (.) do @copy find ./ -name '*.xlsm' -exec cp -prv '{}' "%i"` @lotpings

Comment: @MichaelFroboese - Windows find.exe does not work the same way as Gnu find.

Comment: @MichaelFroboese not sure how you managed to mix two different scripting languages from two different operating systems.

Comment: @Squashman I am just going off things I find online. Again, my first day ever trying to write a batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the current working directory the one where the .bat file script exists using PUSHD. Go back to the previous directory with POPD.

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD %~dp0

SET "TEMPLATE_FILE=Property Inspection Form TEMPLATE.xlsm"

IF NOT EXIST "%TEMPLATE_FILE%" (ECHO ERROR: No template file found in "%CD%" & GOTO TheEnd)

FOR /F "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /B /A:D') DO (
    COPY /Y "%TEMPLATE_FILE%" "%%~d"
)

:TheEnd
POPD
EXIT /B
```

If you want to copy any and all .xlsm files to the subdirectories, you could do something like this. There really should be error checking after the COPY command to see that it worked.

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD %~dp0

FOR /F "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /B /A:D') DO (
    COPY /Y "*.xlsm" "%%~d"
)

:TheEnd
POPD
EXIT /B
```

Comment: Probably not going to see the error message. Might want to put a pause in there.

Comment: Thank you! I believe to get this working I had to add a % to: `PUSHD %~dp0` Working so far though! Is there any way to just grab the '.xlsm' file without specifying the name? So this would work with any .xlsm file regardless of its name? Also @Squashman is right I'm not seeing the error message but thats not really an issue.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much for that edit @lit! Saving my day over here :) really appreciate the help.